# How to create 3d people?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, 3d, cs6

I've seen quite a few of these humanoid creatures around the internet:
[image: http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/80091/80091,1166650199,6/stock-photo--d-cute-abstract-humanoids-play-volley-ball-2357611.jpg]

How do I go about making one of these? Can I make a basic model from cylindrical sections for each joint and then rotate them according to the action?

Comment: This is not a job for Illustrator, you would be much better off just learning Blender

Answer (score 1):

Those images are not created via Illustrator. You need a real, live, 3D application to create such scenes. Illustrator's 3D abilities are severely limited.

If you *really* want to try in Illustrator, you need to be **very** familiar with the Gradient Mesh Tool and be **very** patient when creating.